# how to remove blank values in from array in php

Tags: php, yii

I have used the following code for solving the problem but getting the same output as I mentioned.

Used str_replace(' ','',$var);
user array_filter
123,345,1890,,,567,7898,,,7899,8990,7888

Expected Result : 123,345,1890,567,7898,7899,8990,7888

Comment: Please post your actual code, what you posted is not valid. And what does `$var` contain? A string or an array?

Comment: $var=123,345,1890,,,567,7898,,,7899,8990,7888. it's a string, Now I just wanted to remove blank values which are showing as ,,

Comment: I didn't quite understand, is this the output after `str_replace` or you tried this `str_replace` on this string?

Comment: For an array `explode` it and filter.

Comment: Also, where does this string come from? How is it generated? It makes most sense to try and fix it at generation if possible.

Comment: yes it's the output

Comment: Please add input and expected output properly. It all looks clumsy now.

Comment: Input :  str_replace(' ','',$var); user array_filter 123,345,1890,,,567,7898,,,7899,8990,7888

Expected Result : 123,345,1890,567,7898,7899,8990,7888

Comment: Not this way, with proper indentation and highlighting in your question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I used preg_replace and it works fine :

```
preg_replace('/,[,]+/',',',$var);
```

Comment: only sapce has been added between commas, output is now 123, 345, 1890, , , 567 ,7898, , , 7899, 8990, 7888.

Comment: well if your thing is an array then implode(",", $array); before

Comment: implode(",", $array); This I have already tried but did not work

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(123,345,1890, "","" ,567,7898,"" ,"" ,7899,8990,7888);

 foreach ($arr as $value) {

   if(strcasecmp($value,"")==0){

     $key=array_search("",$arr);
     unset($arr[$key]);

    }else {
      echo "$value <br>";
    }
 }

 foreach ($arr as $value) {echo "$value, ";}
```

**From what I understood try this**

Comment: $arr = array(123,345,1890, ,,,,567,7898,,, ,544,,676 ,7899,8990,7888);

 foreach ($arr as $value) {

   if(strcasecmp($value,"")==0){

     $key=array_search("",$arr);
     unset($arr[$key]);

    }else {
      echo "$value <br>";
    }
 }

 foreach ($arr as $value) {echo "$value, ";}
Tried this code but did not work